# print an array in random order

Tags: java, arrays

how to print an array in random order in java?

example:

int[] myArray = {5,4,3,2,1};

when printed, result should possibly be:

3 2 1 4 5

or

4 3 2 5 1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should look at writing a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle). It's pretty easy to do, and efficient. Effectively you logically partition the array into a "shuffled" part and an "unshuffled part" - then repeatedly pick a random element from the unshuffled part and swap it with the *first* element from the unshuffled part, to make that part of the shuffled part.

Alternatively, create a `List<Integer>` instead and then use [`Collections.shuffle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29). It's unfortunate that there isn't an equivalent for arrays, but Java's type system doesn't do terribly well in terms of making either arrays *or* primitives generic :(

(I'm assuming you know how to do the printing side, and that it's the shuffling side which is the tricky bit for you.)

Comment: http://nshipster.com/random/ is related "How Do I Randomly Order an NSArray?"

Answer (score 2):

Create a new array `order = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}` and shuffle it. Then something like

```
for (int i: order)
    System.out.print(myArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Swap between random elements of array:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = {5,4,3,2,1};

        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i<20; i++) { // 20: is custom number
            int i1 = random.nextInt(myArray.length);
            int i2 = random.nextInt(myArray.length);

            int tmp = myArray[i1];
            myArray[i1] = myArray[i2];
            myArray[i2] = tmp;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
            System.out.print(myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create an instance of the random class and then use the integer i which will be the index. where it lands, compute before element and after element length and then do the same recursively.

Answer (score 0):

int main(){

```
    int array[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int i,k,temp;   
    struct timespec spec;
    long            ms; // Milliseconds

    /* pick a random number from 0 to 9 elements */
    for (i = 9;i>0;i--){

            clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);
            ms = spec.tv_nsec / 1.0e6;
            srand((int )ms);
            temp = rand();
            temp = temp % i;

            printf(" %d  \t  ",array[temp]);


            k = array[i];
            array[i] =  array[temp];
            array[temp] = k;
    }
    printf(" %d  \t \n ",array[0]);
    return 0;
```

}