# Why is this freezing my java program?

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a rubik's cube simulator for my science fair project, and I'm having some trouble. This code is supposed to randomize the cube by setting different color values in the `sideValues[]` array. It's not that complicated, yet it always freezes my computer. (By the way, `method1`,`method2`, and `method 3` are `JLabels`, the counter integers are to make sure that there's no more than 9 pieces per color, drawAndButtons is the `JPanel` the cube is shown on, and cubeSpace is the `JPanel` drawAndButtons is on.)

```
method1.setForeground(Color.red);
            method2.setForeground(Color.black);
            method3.setForeground(Color.black);
            for(int h = 1; h <= 54; h++)
            {
                do
                {
                    transfer = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
                    switch(transfer)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            numy++;
                        case 2:
                            numb++;
                        case 3:
                            numo++;
                        case 4:
                            numg++;
                        case 5:
                            numr++;
                        case 6:
                            numw++;
                        default:
                    }
                    if(numy > 9 || numb > 9 || numo > 9 || numg > 9 || numr > 9 || numw > 9)
                    {
                        rightAmount = false;
                        switch(transfer)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                numy--;
                            case 2:
                                numb--;
                            case 3:
                                numo--;
                            case 4:
                                numg--;
                            case 5:
                                numr--;
                            case 6:
                                numw--;
                            default:
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sideValues[h] = transfer;
                        rightAmount = true;
                    }
                }while(rightAmount == false);
            }
            drawAndButtons.add(new graphics());
            cubeSpace.repaint();
            methodValue = 3;
            numy = 0;
            numb = 0;
            numo = 0;
            numg = 0;
            numr = 0;
            numw = 0;
        }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) (But based on a hunch..) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Wait, add a break after all the miracles gets resolved :)

Comment: Why you don't have any `break;` in your `switch`?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ My twin..... finally found you!

Comment: Try to use `&&`s instead of `||`s in your ` if(numy > 9 || numb`. That maybe causing `rightAmount` to always be `false`, hence a freeze from an infinite loop

Comment: you must use `break;` in every case

Comment: What you're trying to do is randomly "shuffle" an array.  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783008/print-an-array-in-random-order

Comment: Btw. shuffling rubik's cube in such a way may lead to unsolvable configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say one of your variables starting with n (numy, numb, numo …) is greater than 9, but its case's index in `switch` is smaller than current `transfer`. Therefore, you will not decrease it, and the do-while loop will not end. This may potentialy lead to a very-long looping (if your transfer happen to be greater than case-index of the value which is greater than 9). Note this would never happen if your n-starting-variables would be initialized with 0, for example, as if you incremented any of them to be greater than 9, then your second switch would decrement it back. **But how are your n-starting-variables initialized before the method?** (by n-starting-variables I mean numy, numb, numo…)

What is more, as you are not using `break` in your cases, if your transfer = 1, you will execute all the cases 1,2,3,4,5,6 and default, and I am not sure if this is what you want to do here. As I understand you want to increment the "amount" of one-coloured pieces, specified by the pseudo-random number `transfer`. To do so, you must add `break;` in every `case` of your code here, so only the case = `transfer` will be executed.